# Twilio voice SDK javascript not working in mobile browser: AcquisitionFailedError (31402)

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have a very simple HTML page that connects the page to my Twilio backend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@twilio/voice-sdk@2.0.1/dist/twilio.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      connection = null;
      call = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://my.token.endpoint/token"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        const device = new Twilio.Device(data.token);
        connection = await device.connect();
        connection.on(
          "error",
          (err) =>
            (document.getElementById("error-display").innerHTML = err.message)
        );
      };
      stop = () => {
        connection?.disconnect();
        connection = null;
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="call()">call</button>
    <button onclick="stop()">stop</button>
    <p id="error-display"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open the HTML page from my Windows 10 machine using Chrome 102.0.5005.115, clicking the call button successfully connects to my Twilio backend.

However when I open the HTML page from my Android 12 mobile device using Chrome 102.0.5005.125, clicking the call button triggered the following error:

> AcquisitionFailedError (31402): The browser and end-user allowed permissions, however getting the media failed. Usually this is due to bad constraints, but can sometimes fail due to browser, OS or hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue beforehand when trying to register the device before setting the current devices. However, since you're only seeing this on mobile, my guess is it's a permissions issue preventing the audio devices to be set. On your phone, can you try removing all permissions for your browser? Then in the code, print out the devices available input and output devices by console logging these:

```
device.audio.availableInputDevices
device.audio.availableOutputDevices
```

After refreshing the page, your phone should prompt you to allow audio permissions. If not, may need to take a gander through your settings.